# Adding $scope to url params in <script></script>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my angularjs app i have this script for mibew chat in my body where is all my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">Mibew.ChatPopup.init({"id":"58cfa9cad9451969","url":"http://steora.com\/mibew-chat\/chat?locale=en&email={{authentication .username}}.com&name={{authentication .username}}","preferIFrame":true,"modSecurity":false,"width":640,"height":480,"resizable":true,"styleLoader":"\/mibew-chat\/chat\/style\/popup"});
```

i need set username and email`{{authentication .username}` and `{{authentication .email}}`.

In my indexCtrl.js i do this

```
$scope.authentication.username = 'Tom';
$scope.authentication.email= 'tom@gmail.com';
```

But this not working.

Can someone tell my how to scope data to 
Thnx

---

EDIT:
i try solution from @KoIIIeY but if i try to use this, everytime i click on chat icon, its opened in new tab not in popup, and there is no data from email and username. I need to find solution how to pass this data from controller

```
$scope.authentication.username = 'Tom';
```

$scope.authentication.email= 'tom@gmail.com';

to  index.html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">Mibew.ChatPopup.init({"id":"58cfa9cad9451969","url":"http://steora.com\/mibew-chat\/chat?locale=en&email=_____HERE_____&name=____HERE____","preferIFrame":true,"modSecurity":false,"width":640,"height":480,"resizable":true,"styleLoader":"\/mibew-chat\/chat\/style\/popup"})></script>
```

Comment: Why not just call init with needed params?

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that? Thanks

Comment: look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

in indexCtrl.js

```
$scope.init = function(){
    Mibew.ChatPopup.init({"id":"58cfa9cad9451969","url":"http://steora.com\/mibew-chat\/chat?locale=en&email="+$scopeauthentication.email+".com&name="+$scopeauthentication.username+"","preferIFrame":true,"modSecurity":false,"width":640,"height":480,"resizable":true,"styleLoader":"\/mibew-chat\/chat\/style\/popup"});
}
```

in view

```
<body ng-init="init()"></body>
```

Comment: ok i add this like @kellley say.... but now i get error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick"

Comment: object where Property 'open' is undefined.